# How to ignore an argument without deleting it?

Tags: command-line

Say you have a batch file and don't want to delete a specifier, just temporarily ignore it, can this be done in Windows command line?

Comment: well, you can comment out the code that uses that argument

Comment: It's difficult to answer without more specifics. Perhaps you could post a [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing what you want to do.

Comment: what is a "specifier"?  if you mean an environment variable you can temporarily change it. In what language can you temporarily ignore it? what on earth does that even mean?